# YouTube player not playing fullscreen on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, embed, fullscreen

It seems as YouTube embedded videos stopped playing in native player on iOS devices. I have iPhone 5S and all videos started playing within the site instead of native player. Anyone experiencing the same thing? Anyway to force it?
Is this done by some YouTube API library update?

Comment: use YTPPLayerview or uiwebview

Comment: I am talking about regular website within Safari browser, using YouTube embedded iframe.

Comment: As it seems, it's probably caused by recent update to Safari - https://webkit.org/blog/7477/new-web-features-in-safari-10-1/